# Sending a non-maskable interrupt to a virtual machine with VMware Fusion

Tags: macos, virtual-machine, vmware-fusion

I'm using a virtual machine to do kernel debugging on Mac OS X.

Unfortunately, contrary to the Windows equivalent, it's not possible to use the debugger to stop the kernel. To stop it, you have to send the machine a non-maskable interrupt. On a physical machine, you can do that with the correct debug flags at boot, and then holding both ⌘ keys while pressing the power button. However, this key combination can't quite be realized on a virtual machine.

Is it possible to send a non-maskable interrupt to a virtual machine with VMware Fusion?

Answer (score 0):

this helped:
https://cloudtone.wordpress.com/2012/12/13/vmware-fusion-can-you-diag-it-nmi/

This script generated NMI on vmware and with kernel dump configuration, it dumped the core on server machine